# MYSQL Update Tables from another tables

Tags: mysql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlwfQ.png)

how to
 update field booking in the T2 tables corresponding number of requests (LOT) ?? For example if the demand (lots) = 2 then the field stock will change from 0 to 1 twice

Comment: Lelio thanks ... I tried ..update t1 set booking=1 where kode='A'.. but all fields booking code A being 1..but I do not understand the logic to retrieve data from table t2

Comment: add some code snippets

Comment: thanks  Ganesh Karewad..I tried update t1  set booking=1 where code1='A' and code2='w01' limit 1 
now the tables T2 has changed from 0 to 1 as the limit ..
My question becomes how to make the limit values ​​of the table t1 (field lot)??

Answer (score 1):

you can use triggers in mysql to set up an action when values in a row changes, here is an example to create a log when values in employee table are changing,

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER before_employee_update 
BEFORE UPDATE ON employees
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO employees_audit
SET action = 'update',
employeeNumber = OLD.employeeNumber,
lastname = OLD.lastname,
changedat = NOW();
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```